# javascript alerts refuse to work in form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

i keep trying everything to get these alerts to pop up correctly. i started out using nested functions, then threw them out and put it all in one function, and now when I press enter after filling out any one text box it does nothing at all, just puts the strings in the url, instead of alerting like it was before. I'm not sure if its my function call or anything else because I double checked everything and it all seems to check out to me. here is the entire code that doesnt do anything:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Smart Form </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    <!-- VARIABLE DECLARATION -->

    f1.city.focus();

    function check_form()
    {   
        at_sign = email.search(/@/);

        if(document.f1.city.value.length < 1)
        {
            alert('Please enter a city');
            f1.city.focus();
        }
        else if(document.f1.state.value.length != 2 || !(state.charCodeAt('0')>=65 && state.charCodeAt('0')<=91))
        {
            alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
            f1.state.focus();
        }
        else if(document.f1.zip.value.length != 5 || document.f1.zip.value.isNaN()==true)
        {
            alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code');
            f1.zip.focus();
        }
        else if((at_sign<1) || (email.length<3))
        {
            alert('Please enter a valid email address');
            f1.email.focus();
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("Form completed");   
        }

    }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD> 

<BODY >

    <form name = "f1" action="smartform.html">
        <b>City</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "city" size = "18" value="" onSubmit = "javascript:check_form()">
        <b>State</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "state" size = "4" value="" onSubmit = "javascript:check_form()">
        <b>Zip Code</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "zip" size = "5" value="" onSubmit = "javascript:check_form()">
        <b>Email</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "18" value="" onSubmit = "javascript:check_form()">

        <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Done" onclick = "javascript:check_form()">
    </form>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

edit: nothing seems to be working that everyone says.. here is my new code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Smart Form </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    f1.city.focus();

    function check_form(f1)
    {   
        var at_sign = f1.email.search(/@/);

        if(f1.city.value.length < 1)
        {
            alert('Please enter a city');
            f1.city.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(f1.state.value.length != 2 || !(f1.state.charCodeAt('0')>=65 && state.charCodeAt('0')<=91))
        {
            alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
            f1.state.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if((f1.zip.value.length != 5) || (f1.zip.value.isNaN()==true))
        {
            alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code');
            f1.zip.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if((at_sign<1) || (f1.email.length<3))
        {
            alert('Please enter a valid email address');
            f1.email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //document.write("Form completed"); 
        }

        return false;

    }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD> 

<BODY >

    <form name = "f1" onSubmit="return check_form(this)">
        <b>City</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "city" size = "18" value="">
        <b>State</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "state" size = "4" value="">
        <b>Zip Code</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "zip" size = "5" value="">
        <b>Email</b>
        <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "18" value="">

        <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Done" onclick = "return check_form(this)">
    </form>


    <b>hi</b>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

still get no alerts... i put that hi up and got that.. but no alerts......

alright, I know I should probably be using getElementByID, but my new focus is to find out precisely why my code isn't working. Since my lecture outline examples didnt use this method, I want to figure out why the following code doesnt activate alerts like it used to. I simplified it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Smart Form </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">



function check_form()
{   
    document.write("Form started");

    var at_sign = document.f1.email.search(/@/);

    if(document.f1.city.value.length < 1)
    {
        alert('Please enter a city');
        document.f1.city.focus();
        //return false;
    }
    else if(document.f1.state.value.length != 2 || !(document.f1.state.charCodeAt('0')>=65 && document.f1.state.charCodeAt('0')<=91))
    {
        alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
        document.f1.state.focus();
        //return false;
    }
    else if(document.f1.zip.value.length != 5 || isNaN(document.f1.zip.value)==true)
    {
        alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code');
        document.f1.zip.focus();
        //return false;
    }
    else if((at_sign<1) || (document.f1.email.value.length<3))
    {
        alert('Please enter a valid email address');
        document.f1.email.focus();
        //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Form completed");   
    }   
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD> 

<BODY onLoad= "javascript:document.f1.city.focus();">

<form name = "f1" action="smartform1.html" onSubmit="javascript:check_form();">
    <b>City</b>
    <input type = "text" name = "city" size = "18">
    <b>State</b>
    <input type = "text" name = "state" size = "4">
    <b>Zip Code</b>
    <input type = "text" name = "zip" size = "5">
    <b>Email</b>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "18">

    <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Done" onclick = "javascript:check_form();">
</form>




</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I get no errors in console, and now when I type something in, I get the test line "form started" to appear for a split second, along with some mysterious error, and then it all disapears and shows the form. but my question is, why doesnt an alert happen along the way to this result? it seems like even if the page got overwritten, it should still pop up. also, is there a way to pause it with code/and or debugging before it gets to the point where its overwritten? so my basic question is: why don't the alerts pop up, and how do I get the alerts to popup and the focus to remain in the correct field where the function left off within the if/else statement?

update 2: i did a quick screen cap of the errors and it turns out f1.email etc were undefined and indeed causing the thing to not work. So I still want to know how to pause it with code or in the debugger, the posts and links didnt exactly seem to be clear 100% on it. once im in the consonle and in debug mode, where exactly do i go from there to let the program pause on error?

also: if I declare the getElementByID variables at the top of my script in the header, then use them in the function, should that work without all the other event handling methods? I'm attempting this as i type.

Comment: `<-- ... -->` inside a script element is seen as invalid javascript. Also, the *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML5.

Comment: alright.. but i still tried taking that out and nothing changed :(

Comment: Move the onsubmit listener to the form, remove it from all controls. Do not use `javascript:` anywhere. If validation fails, have the function return false. Have the listener return whatever the function returns, e.g. `<form onsubmit="return check_form()"...>`.

Comment: Have you declared `email`?

Comment: i put a document.f1. in front of all the parts i had email.. still nothing

Comment: I also tried moving the onsubmit listener to the form and taking it out each field of the form .. havent tried the return method tho

Comment: now i tried that. nothing seems to allow anything to happen at all...

Comment: Using `alert` is quite possibility the most annoying way to do this kind of thing. Please, for the sake of your users, use error messages embedded in your page close to the fields in question and adjust the CSS style of each invalid form element. jQuery makes this almost ridiculously easy to do, and there are add-ons that make it even easier. Also, this is presumably for the USA only as a 5-digit zip-code is a local preference and excludes virtually every other country on the planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the submit listener on the form and pass a reference to the form, and return whatever value the function returns, e.g.

```
<form onsubmit="return check_form(this);" ...>
```

You should reference the controls as properties of form using their name, don't use the name as a global variable. And declare all variables.

So the function looks like:

```
function check_form(form) {

  var at_sign = email.search(/@/);

  if (form.city.value.length < 1) {
        alert('Please enter a city');
        f1.city.focus();

        // cancel submit by returning false
        return false;

    } else if (form.state.value.length != 2 || !(form.state.charCodeAt(0) >=65 && state.charCodeAt(0)<=91)) {
        alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
        f1.state.focus();
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

You should probably be using a regular expression or lookup for validating the *state* value rather than *charCodeAt*.

Using *document.write* after the page has finished loading (e.g. when submitting the form) will erase the **entire** content of the page before writing the new content.

#### Edit

Here's what's wrong with your new code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
```

Get rid of the language attribute. It's not harmful (well, in a very specific case it might be).

```
f1.city.focus();
```

*f1* has no been defined or initialised (see comments above about element names and global variables)

```
function check_form(f1)
{
    var at_sign = f1.email.search(/@/);
```

*f1.email* is an input element, it has no *search* property, you can't call it. It does have a *value* property that is a string, perhaps you meant:

```
    var at_sign = f1.email.value.search(/@/);
```

Then there is:

```
    else if(f1.state.value.length != 2 || !(f1.state.charCodeAt('0')>=65 && state.charCodeAt('0')<=91))
```

again you have forgotten the *value* property for two of the three expressions, and forgotten to use *f1* in the third. You want:

```
    else if(f1.state.value.length != 2 || !(f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)>=65 && f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)<=91))
```

Note that this requires users to enter the state in capital letters, it might help to tell them about that.

Then there is:

```
    else if((f1.zip.value.length != 5) || (f1.zip.value.isNaN() == true))
```

*isNaN* is a global variable, not a method of strings. If no value has been entered, then the value is the empty string and `isNaN('')` returns false. If you want to test that 5 digits have been entered then use:

```
else if (!/^\d{5}$/test(f1.zip.value))
```

There is no need to test against true, just use it, nor is there a need to group simple expressions:

```
    else if (f1.zip.value.length != 5 || isNaN(f1.zip.value))
```

Then finally, if all the test pass:

```
    return false;
```

that stops the form from submitting. You can omit this return statement, returning *undefined* will let the form submit. Or return *true* if you really want.

Comment: I tried every single thing u said and nothing worked!! AHHH Ill even put my new code up

Comment: I updated my code with your updated suggestions and its working :D the only thing i really need to do now is keep the values in the text box instead of refreshing them to blank values again

Comment: SUCCESSSSSSSSS I just returned false in all if statement sections and changed the onsubmit values to return check_form() and everything now works perfectlY!!!!!!!!!! THANKYOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Answer (score 1):

Ok I want to answer your question but first things first lets walk through your
code and clean it up.
Use this as a template of properly formated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Smart Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Code goes here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tags & attributes don't need to be capitalized. Javascript comments are like this:

```
/** Comment. */
```

Html comments are like this:

```
<!-- Comment. -->
```

Also nitpick: attributes should be followed by an equal sign not a space. i.e.

```
<form name="f1" id="smartForm" action="smartform.html"> ... </form>
```

Next up proper event binding.

```
var smartForm = document.getElementById('smartForm');
smartForm.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
```

Next up I'm going to teach you how to fish real quick so you can figure out why this was broken for you and how to fix these bugs in the future. Open up the developer console. Evergreen browsers (Chrome, Firefox etc...) have good ones these day. The trick you should know is how to evaluate your code so that you can see if you did something wrong or not in how you're accessing your data. So look up how to open up the developer console in your browser for your platform and type this into your console:

```
1+1
```

Should evaluate to: 2. 
Next type: document
If you click around you can see that you can walk through the dom a little bit.
Next load up your smartForm app with my changes above and type:

```
document.getElementById('smartForm')
```

You should see your element. This is how to properly query objects in the dom. 
You'll notice that if you type document.smartForm doesn't work. You should get null, this should tell you that there should be a way to get the element from the document. Hint, it's getElementById. So if you put id's on all your inputs then you can make a list of all the document objects you can query:

```
var cityElement = document.getElementById('city');
var stateElement = document.getElementById('state');
var zipElement = document.getElementById('zip');
var emailElement = document.getElementById('email');
```

Next you can start querying the values and such like you were doing:

```
cityElement.value.length != 2
```

A cleaned up version would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Smart form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id='smartForm' action='smartform.html'>
      <b>City</b>
      <input type="text" id="city" size="18">
      <b>State</b>
      <input type="text" id="state" size="4">
      <b>Zip Code</b>
      <input type="text" id="zip" size="5">
      <b>Email</b>
      <input type="text" id="email" size="18">
      <input type="submit" value="done">
    </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var validateForm = function(evt) {
      var error = false;
      var cityElement = document.getElementById('city');
      var stateElement = document.getElementById('state');
      var zipElement = document.getElementById('zip');
      var emailElement = document.getElementById('email');

      if (cityElement.value.length != 2 ||
          !(state.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && state.charCodeAt(0) <= 91)) {
        error = true;
        alert('oops');
        cityElement.focus();
      }

      // etc..

      if (error) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
    };
    var smartForm = document.getElementById('smartForm');
    smartForm.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ok a couple more things I noticed.  charCodeAt is for strings only. "hi".chatCodeAt not element.charCodeAt. Also you have this random variable at_sign. 
You can save yourself a TON of time and you can learn how to diagnose where the issues are by reading this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console
Learning how to diagnose where the issues are is the single best skill you can learn while trying to get a grapple on javascript. I cannot emphasize this enough, learn how to debug, and you will learn how to program orders of magnitude faster. Trust me, let debugging tutorials be your bread at butter!

Full working example of your code:
http://codepen.io/JAStanton/pen/tjFHn?editors=101

A little less verbose version:
http://codepen.io/JAStanton/pen/iBJAk?editors=101

Comment: I tried this example and added in the else if's for the other elements while editing it appropriately to make it follow like the first if statement and it wouldnt alert after the first run through... I also want to know what precisely is making my original not working since i was following the lecture outline when writing it :(

Comment: Ok first in your revised code you will see that f1 is undefined (f1.email.focus) (open up the console). Next if you insert this line 'debugger' with the console open and click submit you will insert debug mode (with console window open). here you can type variables into the console and see what their values are. f1 is indeed the form element, but f1.email is undefined. You need to get element w/ element.getElementById (f1.getElementById or document.getElementById).

Comment: I see what u were saying with the getElement when i did a quick screen cap of the error, but how can I get the console to pause the error before it dissapears?

Comment: thanks for posting your version it did indeed work in your codepen site. I would have used that if i couldnt figure out how to fix my own code, but rob fixed it so I'm going with his for the sake of originality. thanks though!

Comment: Thats fine by you got to learn how to debug using the console. If you don't you'll be coming back here every time you get a bug in your code. Vs being able to find them yourselves.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I sort of did get the console debugging to work, got it running to the point where it solved me 3 or 4 errors. this really is a tremendous vital tool to keep learning javascript.

Answer (score 0):

onSubmit goes in the form, not the inputs, w/o the javascript: Solved =p

```
<form onsubmit="return check_form();" ...
```

There are several mishaps in your code that might also cause errors and prevent that from working

Also, check if there are mistakes (like the HTML comment inside script), if an error happens in javascript and is untreated, all javascript in that context stops working. You can check that with any browser debugger (usually F12 will show you a window and display errors if they happen)